# ListView Search Filter leaves unwelcome data

Tags: java, android, listview, search, filter

I have some issue with Search Filter in my ListView. When i type letters of my objects into the searchbox, it searches normally. But when I add anything else, the items stay in the ListView in spite of the fact that it doesn't contain that text. You can see it in the picture.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this?

[image: Picture]

Adapter with filter class (below):

```
public class AnimalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Animal> implements Filterable{
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Animal> mAnimals;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    Activity activity;
    AnimalAdapter adapter;
    private Filter animalFilter;
    private List<Animal> animaly;
    ListView mListView;
    RelativeLayout row;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public AnimalAdapter(Context context, List<Animal> objects) {
          super(context, R.layout.animal_row_item, objects);


          ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();

          imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config);
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

            this.mContext = context;
            this.mAnimals = objects;
            this.animaly = objects;

      }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
          if(convertView == null){
              LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
              convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_row_item, null);
          }


          final Animal animal = mAnimals.get(position);


          TextView animalView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
          TextView areaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area_text);

          final ImageView animalPic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_pic);
          final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

          indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          animalPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Setup a listener we can use to switch from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
            ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                    indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    animalPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View view, FailReason arg2) {


                }

            };

          imageLoader.displayImage(animal.getImgUrl(), animalPic,options, listener);
          animalView.setText(animal.getAnimal());
          areaView.setText(animal.getArea());


          convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MoreActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("about", animal.getAbout());
                    intent.putExtra("animal", animal.getAnimal());
                    intent.putExtra("imgUrl", animal.getImgUrl());
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
          });

          return convertView;
      }




     public int getCount() {
         return mAnimals.size();
 }


     @Override
     public Filter getFilter() {
             if (animalFilter == null)
                     animalFilter = new AnimalFilter();

             return animalFilter;

     }

     private class AnimalFilter extends Filter {



         @Override
         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

             FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                 // We implement here the filter logic
                 if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                         // No filter implemented we return all the list
                         results.values = animaly;
                         results.count = animaly.size();


                 }
                if (constraint!= null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                    List<Animal> nAnimalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
                         for (Animal p : animaly) {
                                 if (p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())
                                         &&p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))


                                     nAnimalList.add(p);


                                 if (p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())
                                         &&!p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                                     nAnimalList.remove(p);


                         }

                         results.values = nAnimalList;
                         results.count = nAnimalList.size();  
                 }

                 return results;
         }

         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
         protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                         FilterResults results) {

                 // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
                 if (results.count == 0)
                         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                 else {
                     mAnimals = (List<Animal>) results.values;
                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

         }

 }


}
```

Comment: Off topic but I like the cute kitty pic :3

Comment: lol hahaha. good choice huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I think your logic populating the List might be off (i.e. there is no need to do .remove() on a list that starts empty), your error might be in publishResults:

```
if (results.count == 0)
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();     // <-- this isn't right
else 
{
     mAnimals = (List<Animal>) results.values;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

notifyDataSetInvalidated() likely isn't what you want to do to empty your list, do this instead:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
{
     // even if results.values is an empty List<Animal>, you want to notify your adapter!
     mAnimals = (List<Animal>) results.values;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer CSmith. And how do i achieve, that the list will be empty, when no result fits? (doesn't start with certain letter or doesn't contain some sequence)

Comment: the above suggestion should work, assuming your list is populated by mAnimals, if mAnimals references an empty List<Animal>.

Comment: After few minutes of thinking about your answer, I finally got the idea. It is true, but I think, that if i set the function contains and staetsWith, the text (for example "pandasnifsdni...") also appears there, because it contains at least part of the sequence. Am I true?

Comment: @mansoulx has the filtering logic correct (you only need to check for contains() to see if the string exists anywhere in the result), combine his solution with mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
if (constraint!= null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
    List<Animal> nAnimalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    for (Animal p : animaly) {
    if (p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
        nAnimalList.add(p);
    }
    results.values = nAnimalList;
    results.count = nAnimalList.size();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didnt work. Still, when I type different letters, the rest stays in the same place.

Comment: I did some improvements which did @CSmith suggest me and combined it with your advice and it finally works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) 
&& !p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
    nAnimalList.remove(p);
}
```

Let's look at what each statement evaluates to. The first one is false because "panda" does not contain "pansjdghas". The second one is true because "panda" does not start with "pansdjlha" but you negate that to make it true. Because the first one is false, you never reach the code that removes the animal. To fix this, simply negate the first statement as well so it is true. Your code should now look like this:

```
if (!p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) 
&&  !p.getAnimal().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
    nAnimalList.remove(p);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get why the animal has to be removed. It shouldn't be added in the first place, right?

Comment: Hi Nathan thanks for answer, but it didn't work. Ascorbin: i want to remove/hide all objects, if nothing starts with and contains charsequence, and show a Toast that nothing was found.